# Snakemake not playing nicely with wget

Tags: python, wget, snakemake

I'm trying to use `snakemake` to download files from a website, then cat them together.

However, I always get the error:`Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 24 of /path/to/Snakefile:`

Why doesn't `snakemake` just wait for the files to download before trying to proceed? It would be inconvenient for me to have all of the reads in different directories, and I do not want to bother making a config file since this is a one-off `Snakefile`.

Thanks!

Here is my script:

```
import os
rule all:
    input:
        "ONT/yeastONT_combined.fastq.gz",
        "trimmed/ERR1938684_1.trim.final.fastq.gz",
        "trimmed/ERR1938684_2.trim.final.fastq.gz",
        "trimmed/ERR1938684_1.trim.unpaired.fastq.gz",
        "trimmed/ERR1938684_2.trim.unpaired.fastq.gz"

rule getONTfwd:
    input:

    output:
        "ONT/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz"

    shell:
        """cd ONT \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/005/ERR1883385/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz' \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/006/ERR1883386/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz' \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/007/ERR1883387/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz' \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/003/ERR1883393/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz' \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/005/ERR1883395/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz' \
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/006/ERR1883396/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz' \
        sleep 300 \
        cd .."""

rule combine_ONT:
    input:
        f1 = "ONT/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz",
        f2 = "ONT/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz",
        f3 = "ONT/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz",
        f4 = "ONT/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz",
        f5 = "ONT/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz",
        f6 = "ONT/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "ONT/yeastONT_combined.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        """cat {input.f1} {input.f2} {input.f3} {input.f4} {input.f5} {input.f6} > {output}"""
```

Comment: Snakemake waits for your shell command to terminate. If the file is not there afterwards, it will complain. Just make sure that when your shell command terminates, the file is there. Usually, wget only completes after the download is finished, so the file should be actually there. I suggest to manually debug your wget commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in shell command of rule `getONTfwd` where you escape every newline with  `\`; this leads to complete shell command being treated as one single command. Either remove escape character `\` or add semicolon before escape symbol to separate the commands (i.e. `; \`)

Also,`sleep 300` is not necessary if you used them just to provide buffer time to download all files. As mentioned in comments by Johannes, `wget` exits only file from url is downloaded. And, rule for files `trimmed/*.fastq.gz` is missing in your example script.

Below is edited version of your example, which should work as expected:

```
import os
rule all:
    input:
        "ONT/yeastONT_combined.fastq.gz",
        # "trimmed/ERR1938684_1.trim.final.fastq.gz",
        # "trimmed/ERR1938684_2.trim.final.fastq.gz",
        # "trimmed/ERR1938684_1.trim.unpaired.fastq.gz",
        # "trimmed/ERR1938684_2.trim.unpaired.fastq.gz"

rule getONTfwd:
    output:
        "ONT/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz",
        "ONT/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz"

    shell:
        """cd ONT
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/005/ERR1883385/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz'
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/006/ERR1883386/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz'
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/007/ERR1883387/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz'
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/003/ERR1883393/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz'
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/005/ERR1883395/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz'
        wget 'ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR188/006/ERR1883396/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz'
        cd .."""

rule combine_ONT:
    input:
        f1 = "ONT/ERR1883385_1.fastq.gz",
        f2 = "ONT/ERR1883386_1.fastq.gz",
        f3 = "ONT/ERR1883387_1.fastq.gz",
        f4 = "ONT/ERR1883393_1.fastq.gz",
        f5 = "ONT/ERR1883395_1.fastq.gz",
        f6 = "ONT/ERR1883396_1.fastq.gz"
    output:
        "ONT/yeastONT_combined.fastq.gz"
    shell:
        """cat {input.f1} {input.f2} {input.f3} {input.f4} {input.f5} {input.f6} > {output}"""
```